# What are the pros and cons of louvered gutter alternatives?

Tags: gutters, rain

One part of our house has a gutter nearly 30' above grade (a dry-laid brick patio outside a walkout basement), which never gets cleaned out because I don't enjoy being on a ladder that high, and that part of the roof is not accessible from the other side (it's a non-traditional contemporary house).   Luckily, because of the height, this takes several years to clog completely with leaves, but it's now time to do something agin.

I'm considering [Rainhandler](http://www.rainhandler.com/) "gutters" to replace the traditional gutter on this section.  It's about a 28' run, and drains approximately 12' of roof (it's a shed roof Lthat butts into a wall).   The eave is about 16" deep.

What should I consider before making this decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Rainhandler Plus might be OK if the ground around your home's foundation slopes at least 1 inch per foot for 6 feet or more and you haven't had water leaks in your basement or home. But you'll find gutter-guard systems that are better at capturing water for far less.

[Consumer Reports 2010](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/magazine-archive/2010/september/home-garden/gutter-guard/rainhandler-plus/index.htm)

My gutters are 3 stories above the ground level (it's a townhouse), so we had Gutterglove installed. It's been a year and we haven't had any problems. I previously had some cheaper screens on my gutters that lasted about 8 years before buckling from leaves (there's a steep hill behind my house so we do get leaves even on a roof that tall).  I haven't had any problem with the gutterglove system, but it also hasn't been long.